# how to change Post Icons in wordpress according to the type of posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a simple blog using WordPress.

What I want to do is that whenever I post something, according to the content the post icon should automatically change. For example, if the post contain a video, there should be a video icon or if post contains a image, the post icon should change to image icon etc.

I am completely new to wordpress, so please help in a bit layman's term.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: If you have different post-formats and want to change the icon according to the post-format then you will have to create content-{post-format} files for each and there you can include the icon in the loop for the specific post-format..

Comment: @DhavalChheda I didn't get you completely. Can you elaborate or redirect me to any helpful link ?

Comment: check this to start with..this will provide you info on post-formats..https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats